# How to map column data from two tables into a 3rd in SQL?

Tags: sql, join

Table A

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | b |
| c | d |

Table B

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | e |
| b | f |
| c | g |
| d | h |

Result :

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| e | f |
| g | h |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join ***table B*** *twice* such as

```
SELECT B1.col2 AS col1, B2.col2
  FROM A
  JOIN B B1
    ON B1.col1 = A.col1
  JOIN B B2 
    ON B2.col1 = A.col2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5a9805b0add27e4c5007a1b2b048715)</kbd>